# Sqlite query cut off

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord.js

I'm creating a discord.js bot, and one thing that it does is querying for a server ID with a nickname that has been registered in a table by a user.

**Heres the registering part**

```
if (message.content.startsWith(`${config.prefix}setname`)) {
        const serverid = message.guild.id;
        console.log(serverid);
        const query = `SELECT * FROM dict1 WHERE serverID = ?`;
        db.get(query, [serverid], (err, row) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }

            if (row === undefined) {
                const nick = message.content.slice(9);
                const query2 = `SELECT * FROM dict1 WHERE nick = ?`;
                db.get(query2, [nick], (err, row2) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    }

                    if (row2 === undefined) {
                        const insertdata = db.prepare(`INSERT INTO dict1 VALUES(?,?)`);
                        insertdata.run(nick, serverid);
                        insertdata.finalize();
                        message.reply('Done! Nickname set to: ' + nick);
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        message.reply('This nick is already taken');
                    }
                });
            }

            else {
                message.reply('This server already has a nickname set!');
            }
        });
    }
```

Now the server id that was grabbed shows up in the table fully, but its when I retrieve it that the server id shows up with missing and changed digits.

**Grabbing Part**

```
if (msg.channel.type == 'dm' && msg.content.startsWith('!goto')) {
        const sentMessage = msg.content.slice(6);
        const query = `SELECT * FROM dict1 WHERE nick = ?`;
        db.get(query, [sentMessage], (err, row) => {
            console.log(row);
            const temp1 = row.serverID;
            global.destinationServer = String(temp1);
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
        });
```

The actual server ID is 726202918700712008 but when logging the row which matches the requested nickname it shows up as 726202918700712100

**I hope, the data I have provided helps and thank you in advance! :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

For anyone else having this problem store the server-id as a string, not an integer.